# How should i map an enum implementing an interface with hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, enums

Let me explain with code :

```
public interface A {}

public enum B implements A{}

public enum C implements A{}

@Entity
@Table(name = "land")
public class D extends ABSDBOperations {
private A a;

public A getA(){
return a;
}
public void setA(A a){
this.a=a;
}
}
```

what annotation should i use above `getA()` to be able to persist `a` attribute?

Comment: I don't think that is possible to map an Interface with JPA.

Comment: i know that. so there is no work around?

Comment: What about in hbm file?

Comment: I can only image to use the `@OneToOne` annotation on `a` in combination with the attribute `targetEntity=B.class` as a fixed information which variant of `A` is to be used at runtime by the persistence provider. However, I doubt, that you want only want to make use of `B` but instead want to persist objects of  both `B` and `C` via the field `a`. Is that correct or a you "free" to fix a certain type?